# Get dynamic file name in CLI dataloader (import)

Tags: data-loader, salesforce-id, salesforcedx-cli, dataloader-batch

How to get dynamic file name with name example "NameFileFormatYYYYMMDD.csv"?
My code looks like this

```
<bean id="accountInsert"
    class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
    singleton="false">
    <description>accountInsert job gets the account record from the CSV file 
        and inserts it into Salesforce.</description>
    <property name="name" value="accountInsert"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\samples\status\accountInsertSoapTrace.log"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://login.salesforce.com"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="myinstance@salesforce.com.dev"/>

            <entry key="sfdc.password" value="b96ff3a87e78db1eeb24c931ad7afab741f2e60f8220b89d05b047b2dff41468"/>
            <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\bin\dataLoader.key"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="10"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="insert"/>
            <entry key="process.mappingFile" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\bin\accountInsertMap.sdl"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\bin\insertAccounts*.csv"/>
            <entry key="process.outputSuccess" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\bin\accountInsert_success.csv"/>
            <entry key="process.outputError" 
                value="C:\Users\EnrikoIr\dataloader\v47.0.0\bin\accountInsert_error.csv"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead"/>
            <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" 
                value="2005-12-01T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There's another workaround to create another task for rename file, but is it possible we put variable in dataAccess.name?

Thanks for help

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're invoking the job via the command line in Windows, then you can specify parameters in the command line.  To parameter for Data Access name is **dataAccess.name**.  To learn more, check out the [Data Loader Process Configuration Parameters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_params.htm&type=5) page.